# why does aws EC2 instance automatically starts after manually stopping it?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, instance

I have a AWS EC2 instance. To avoid more billing , iam manually selecting the instance and stopping it. However in sometime i automatically starts back thereby adding to my billing. How do i permanently stop it and start manually only when i want to

Comment: did you try my solution? Did it work? If yes, please accept it.

Comment: yes, deleted the auto scaling group and  then terminated the machines

Comment: Good to know it solved your problem!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your EC2 instance must be in an auto-scaling group with a number of instance set to 1.

If you don't need it you can just delete this group and your instance will not start automatically.

Note : You can also check Amazon OpsWorks and Amazon CloudFormation.